# Print whole line in red if some numeric value is higher than 0

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I have an out put that shows this, is a dimm diag result.

[image]

But i want to print in red only the result that are higher than 0, the rest should be in the default color. So the result only comes after the ':', the rest is the dimm location so that doesn't matter.

I  tried this so far

```
awk -F ' *: *' '$2 ~ $1 > 0 {print "\033[31m" $0"\033[0m"; next} 1' test.txt
```

But I get this

[image]

Comment: @Cbhihe Here it is =)

Comment: [edit] your question to show textual sample input and expected output. We can't copy/paste an image to test a potential solution with.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex match is weird, I'm not sure what you were going for there.

This works for my little test file:

```
awk -F":" '$2 !~ /^0 /  {print "\033[31m" $0"\033[0m"; next} 1' test.txt
```

**test.txt:**

```
Hello:0 D1
Hello:1 D2
Hello:10 D12
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @muru!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ awk -F ' *: *|[[:blank:]]' '$2>0 {print "\033[31m" $0"\033[0m"; next} 1' test.txt
```

It should work even for value of `$2` that are written `02`or `0011`if they occur at all. This also sticks to your logic of testing by numerical value (where `00`is actually zero and `021`is 21) not by character value which is what `$2 !~ /^0/` (note absence of space after `0`) or `$2 !~ /^0 /` (note the space after `0` as in the other answer) do. It does so by specifying two possible field separators: `' *: *'` and `'[[:blank:]]'` which covers plain spaces and tabs.

Note that the above will print the record in red if the second field (`$2`) is anything but either 0 or missing.

Answer (score 1):

Untested since we don't have sample input/output to test with but this may be what you want:

```
awk -F ':' '($2+0) > 0 {$0 = "\033[31m" $0 "\033[0m"} 1' test.txt
```